# Content DIV hidden by footer

Tags: css, html

I've noticed that when I do have a long text on my web page I can not see the full text even when scrolling down the max. In this example http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/yYBE5/ it looks like the end of the paragraph is hidden (behind the footer?). How can I fix this and have the text zone (DIV content-right) to stop where the footer begins?
Many thanks

CSS:

```
@charset"UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

Html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 53%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(247,247,247,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 53%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 53%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 53%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 53%, rgba(247,247,247,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f7f7f7', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: solid 4px #00539E;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 35px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#header-text {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
}
/* mainmenu */

#mainmenu {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* min-height: 180px; */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -52px;
    /* padding-top: -42px; */
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    color: #FFF;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
#mainmenu>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li a, #mainmenu ul ul:hover li a {
    color: #333;
    padding-left: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all, transform;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #005EBC;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-property: all, transform;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
}
p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #0064C5;/* display: inline-block; */
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #BBB;/* display: inline-block; */
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
H5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    background: rgb(29,115,196); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */

    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(29,115,196,1) 0%, rgba(0,100,197,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(29,115,196,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,100,197,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(29,115,196,1) 0%, rgba(0,100,197,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(29,115,196,1) 0%, rgba(0,100,197,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(29,115,196,1) 0%, rgba(0,100,197,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(29,115,196,1) 0%, rgba(0,100,197,1) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1d73c4', endColorstr='#0064c5', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
div#content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
div#content-headline {
    float: right;
    width: 55%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div#content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 55%;
    max-height: 60%;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
div#content-center {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* footer */
#main_footer {
    clear:both;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    background: #cfc8c0;
    height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    bottom:0;
}
#main_footer #lien_hot_news {
    background: #e14242 url(pics/hot_news.gif) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic normal 24px Georgia, serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    height: 38px;
    width: 145px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
#main_footer #lien_hot_news:hover {
    background-color: #e92c26;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    background: #fff url(pics/dernier_tweet_gauche.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet .lien_twitter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet .inner {
    max-width: 550px;
    background: url(../images/picto/dernier_tweet_droite.gif) right 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 4px 15px 5px 53px;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet a {
    color: #75716c;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet a:hover {
    color: #444;
}
#main_footer #dernier_tweet .last_tweet {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main_footer .autres_liens {
    position: absolute;
    right: 12px;
    top: 9px;
    font: italic normal 15px Georgia, serif;
    color: #95897c;
}
#main_footer .autres_liens .label {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#main_footer .autres_liens a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#main_footer .autres_liens a img {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: your footer is position fixed so it goes over top of the content. You need to add some padding bottom or margin bottom to your content container, 46px of it, since your footer is 46px tall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Max height` and put `padding-bottom: 42px`

```
div#content-right {
float: right;
width: 55%;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 42px;
}
```

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/yYBE5/3/

Comment: this would not work when the left content is bigger than right content

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/yYBE5/5/

Your footer is positioned fixed so it will go over top of your regular content. I added a content container and give it

```
#content_container {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
}
```

Apparently margin bottom does not work in Chrome so I updated it to margin-bottom

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that does not seem to be working (text should end by "END END END" but I does not see this part in jsfiddle... Any thoughts?

Comment: I did check @Huangism's fiddle and it does work (tested in FF).

Comment: Adding the wrapper element `content_container` is probably the best and more bullet-proof approach. +1 for thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

Adding padding-bottom to the body won't work

**Solution:**

Updating the fiddle given by Huangism. adding padding-bottom to the `content-container` div

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/yYBE5/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#main_footer .autres_liens a img {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

The width is your culprit. Remove it, or accommodate it for the images that should be there.

Comment: You must be answering a different question

Comment: @Huangism Why's that haha? I think this is pretty much what he's looking for no? It corrrects the cutoff and realigns the text to be flush with the edge fo the footer.